# max-height not working for div slidein from bottom

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to create a website with a few image. When the user hovers over an image, a div will slide out from the bottom of the page with some information about the image. Similair to this page: https://bewegen.com/en/bike-share-network

This is what I have now:

https://jsfiddle.net/ugto4sr5/4/

```css
.box {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 0rem;/* approximate max height */
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: in-ease-out;
}

img:hover+.box {
  max-height: 30rem;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://assets.pernod-ricard.com/nz/media_images/test.jpg?hUV74FvXQrWUBk1P2.fBvzoBUmjZ1wct" alt="" height=3 0 width=3 0>
<div class="box">
</div>
```

It works as it should, but if I copy the code to my file and run it. The max-height is not working, it stays as 20 rem before I hover.

Comment: you are set box size to 20rem and after hover you cant set maxHeight 30rem, add min-height in hover, it works

Comment: that is not the problem, the fiddle is working fine.

Comment: @FoxOnFireHD Do you have the same HTML structure in your file? Try changing `img:hover + .box` to `img:hover ~ .box`